# Sinatra - Overriding Rack Classes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a tiny Sinatra project where I need to override `Rack::Auth::Basic#valid?`. Currently I have placed this override in the main file for my application, but that seems to clutter the source as things get bigger...

```
require "sinatra/base"

module Rack::Auth
  class Basic
    def valid?(auth)
      # My overrides go here...
    end
  end
end

class App < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "CustomRealm" do |username, password|
    # Authentication
  end

  get "/" do
    erb :index
  end
end
```

I'd like to move the overrides to an external file. My project structure is something along the lines of

```
* views
|------ index.erb
* config.ru
* app.rb
* README.md
* LICENSE.md
* Gemfile
* Gemfile.lock
```

Where can I move the `Rack::Auth` overrides so that I can use them from inside `app.rb`? I have tried to put them on `lib/rack/auth/basic.rb` but that didn't work at all... What's the Sinatra standards on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a "standard" for this in Sinatra. But this shouldn't be too hard to do.

The simplest thing you can do is create a `rack_overrides.rb` and require that from your `app.rb`.

Sinatra does not come with features like auto loading (like Rails does), so it doesn't magically pick up things from `lib/` or other directories.

Oh, and just out of curiosity: Why do you need to override `Rack::Auth::Basic#valid?`?

Comment: +1. As an alternative I would put the code in `lib/rack/auth.rb`, as that's how you'd do it if Rack wasn't an external library.